# Jquery Mobile popup triggering by itself

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a popup set up on the index.html as follows:

```html
<!-- Choice Popup -->
<div class="ui-popup-screen ui-overlay-a ui-screen-hidden" id="popupDialog-screen"></div>
<div data-role="popup" class="ui-popup-container ui-overlay-a" data-transition="pop" id="choicePopup">
    <div data-role="popup" id="choicePopup" data-overlay-theme="b" data-theme="c" data-dismissible="false" class="ui-corner-all ui-popup ui-body-c ui-overlay-shadow" aria-disabled="false" data-disabled="false" data-shadow="true" data-corners="true" data-transition="slidedown" data-position-to="window" data-arrow="true" data-arrow-sides="t,b,l,r">
        <div data-role="content" data-theme="d" class="ui-corner-bottom ui-content ui-body-d" role="main">
             <h1 class="ui-title" role="heading" aria-level="1">Your decision has been made:</h1>

             <h2 align="center" id="choice-p"></h2>
               <a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-rel="back" data-theme="c" data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" class="ui-btn ui-btn-up-c ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-btn-inline">
                    <span class="ui-btn-inner">
                        <span class="ui-btn-text">Thanks</span>
                    </span>
               </a>
               <a href="#" onclick="eatsome('Food'); return false;" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-transition="flow" data-theme="b" data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" class="ui-btn ui-btn-up-b ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-btn-inline">
                    <span class="ui-btn-inner">
                        <span class="ui-btn-text">Again!</span>
                    </span>
               </a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The problem is, I don't know why its booting on loading, some attribute is triggering it, can anyone find the issue? Thank you

Comment: Instead of rendered provide **source** markup and for all page, not just popup. Better yet create [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) which reproduces the problem.

Comment: @peterm [link] http://jsfiddle.net/wigiri/PkKLd/

Comment: And where is the popup in that jsfiddle?

Comment: @peterm sorry, forgot to add it: [link] http://jsfiddle.net/wigiri/PkKLd/

Comment: @peterm had the wrong link.... [link] http://jsfiddle.net/wigiri/PkKLd/7/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues with your markup and code:

**First of all** your markup for the popup looks already jQM-enhanced like being copied from the browser's developer view. Therefore make it normal first. It might look like

```html
<div data-role="popup" id="choicePopup" data-overlay-theme="b" data-theme="c" data-dismissible="false" class="ui-corner-all">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="a" class="ui-corner-top">
        <h1></h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content" data-theme="d" class="ui-corner-bottom ui-content">
        <h3 class="ui-title">Your decision has been made:</h3>
        <a id="btnThanks" href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-rel="back" data-theme="c">Thanks</a>
        <a id="btnAgain" href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-rel="back" data-transition="flow" data-theme="b">Again!</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Second** a popup markup **[should reside inside the same page as the link](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0/docs/widgets/popup/)** that opens it.

```html
<div data-role="page" id="main">
    ...
    <div data-role="popup" id="choicePopup">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

**Third** use proper [jQM events](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pageinit/) to place your code that manipulates the content.

**Forth** Stop using `onclick` and other `on*` event attributes with jQM. Once again use proper jQM or jQuery events. 
So instead of

```html
<a href="#" onclick="eatsome('Food'); return false;" ... >Again!</a>
```

use

```html
<a id="#btnAgain" href="#" ... >Again!</a>
```

```js
$("#btnAgain").click(function(){
    eatsome('Food'); 
    return false;
});
```

**Fifth** After injecting html you need to call `trigger('create')` on a parent element to let jQM enhance and style the markup that you injected.

```js
var content = '<form>;
...
content += '</form>;
$("div.settings-content").html(content).trigger("create");
```

**And here is working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pmatseykanets/TyHGk/)** based on your markup. As you can see the popup doesn't pop up on its own. There are two buttons that show how to open the popup declaratively and programmatically. And content for settings page is injected and styled properly.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response!! I am learning JQuery on the fly with this project, so all the detail helps a lot. I did that and the user click a link on one page and sends the user to another page. In this other page the popup shows up, but with the code above, the popup  is rendered not in the center of the new page but because of the slide transition as the center as if there where 2 pages. You have any ideas to solve this? Thank again for the response before

Comment: I'm glad it helped. To center a popup in the browser window (if that was your question) use `data-position-to="window"` attribute on a anchor that opens the popup. See more about positioning popups **[here](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0/docs/widgets/popup/).** I also updated jsFiddle to make both declarative and programmatic ways to open the popup work the same (with slideup transition and center it in the browser window)

Comment: I am having an issue launching the popup from another javascript file, I boot the popup correctly form the index.html (had to put the javascript in the #main <div> now I can't launch it from a helper.js file (it loads the content properly as before but when I click the <a> it doesn't launch the popup, whilst I copied the same code and it works straight in the index.html. Do you have any clues on this?

Comment: @Wigiri That seems to be a good subject for another question. Post it ONLY with relevant code and other SO members or I will be happy to help.